# Qt Designer (creator) widget box like widget

Tags: c++, qt, widget, qt-creator, qt-designer

Is there a good example or complete code for Qt Designer (creator) widget box like widget with QWidget or QFrame within? So it should work like QToolBox or QTabWidget but be expandable: possible to view few pages (widgets) at a time, not single one like QToolBox or QTabWidget or QStackedWidget provide.

[image]

Or need to write myself using QTreeWidget for example? Need same look and feel with same root decoration on category button (or panel) in in Qt Creator or with line like following:

```
+ ——- Category 1 ————
widgets
widgets
+ ——- Category 2 ————
widgets
widgets
etc
```

If it exists with plugin to Qt Creator - even better.

Comment: Qt Creator is Open Source, get the code from the git page and see how it is implemented (http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt-creator/qt-creator.git/)
Hint: Get the code, open in QtCreator and search for a text visible on the widget, such as "Command Link Button" or "Item Views (Model-Based)". But make sure to stay within the licence if they do something custom.

Comment: I looked at it - not what I need I think. It is VERY complex and it contains much unnecessary things for me. There is a class `WidgetBoxTreeWidget` but it contains many explicit functionality for me. If no better solution found will try to cut it to usable state.

Comment: basically it is a tree displaying text and icons and the `Category n` objects are styled different

Comment: The WidgetBox is a QTreeWidget with custom toplevel items and very little indent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Created sample widget and plugin for Qt Designer, put it on GitHub if somebody else need this and want to improve: https://github.com/akontsevich/WidgetBox. It is ready for using however some points good to have improved:

- Style category button (or panel) closer to Qt Creator (Designer) look 
  or like to [LibreOffice Writer Properties Tool Box](https://github.com/akontsevich/WidgetBox/blob/master/Screenshots/LibreOffice%20Writer%20Properties.png?raw=true) on the right side
- Fix isPageExpanded propery change in Qt Designer

Hope for community participation or suggestions on these improvements.

Sample screenshots of current state:

[image] [image]